# What is the difference between Cell, SXSSFCell and XSSFCell?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

From the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) I came to know that `SXSSFCell` and `XSSFCell` are the implementing classes of `Cell`, but I am trying to understand the difference between different implementations. If I want to export data to excel, so which `Cell` implementation should I use? What exactly is the difference between `SXSSFCell` and `XSSFCell` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well in summary SXSSFCell is just an extension of XSSFCell. When to use it is making a large spreadsheets. If you are not making a huge spreadsheets then use only XSSFCell.

Check more the documentation:

> SXSSF is an API-compatible streaming extension of XSSF to be used when
> very large spreadsheets have to be produced, and heap space is
> limited. SXSSF achieves its low memory footprint by limiting access to
> the rows that are within a sliding window, while XSSF gives access to
> all rows in the document. Older rows that are no longer in the window
> become inaccessible, as they are written to the disk.

From https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/

Comment: "SXSSFCell is just an extension of XSSFCell": This is not true. The cell classes `HSSFCell`, `SXSSFCell`, `XSSFCell` all extend `CellBase` which implements the interface `Cell`. What the `SXSSFCell` and `XSSFCell` have in common ist, that both handle cells of Office Open XML (`*.xlsx`) while `HSSFCell` handles cells of binary BIFF file system (`*.xls`).